# Very poor Marshmallow performance

Tags: python, performance, marshmallow

I have a Flask+Marshmallow+SQLAlchemy based back-end application, and while profiling it I realized that the majority of the CPU time is spent doing simple Marshmallow schema serialization.

Consider the following example:

```py
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class TestSchema(Schema):
    a = fields.Int()
    b = fields.Int()
    c = fields.Int()
    d = fields.Int()

test_data = {"a": 123, "b": 456, "c": 789, "d": 111}

schema = TestSchema()

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

for i in range(0, 10):
    schema.load(test_data)

end_time = datetime.datetime.now()

delta = end_time - start_time
ms = delta.total_seconds() * 1000
print(str(ms))  # 1.013669
```

This simple schema, loaded 10 times takes over 1ms (!) on my 4.38 GHz Core i7. This is just 4 integers, no complex types, no nested fields, no fancy validation.

In my case, I have a couple of mid-sized objects that are loaded/dumped to/from SQLALchemy models. A couple of dozen fields and several levels of nesting each (around 100 fields total per object including nested), takes around **50+** ms of the pure CPU time to load. This is before any json serialization, any computation or business logic..

What this means in practice, is simple Marshmallow schema work and nothing else, would allow only for 10-20 requests per second before the CPU reaches 100%.

To make sure I am not crazy, I have re-written this example in C#:

```cs
class TestSchema
{
    public int Id;
    public int ItemId;
    public float Value;
    public int Level;
}

JObject testData = new JObject();
testData["Id"] = 123;
testData["ItemId"] = 123;
testData["Value"] = 123.456f;
testData["Level"] = 123;

testData.ToObject<TestSchema>(); // First time Newtonsoft library caches reflection

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    var a = testData.ToObject<TestSchema>();
}

sw.Stop();

double ms = sw.ElapsedTicks / 10000d;
Console.WriteLine($"{ms}"); // 0.0767
```

C# which I have always considered slower than most languages/frameworks, performs basically the same work 13 times faster on the same machine. What's curious is that Newtonsoft statically caches a bunch of slow reflection calls and subsequent serialization calls are much faster. Marshmallow doesn't seem to be doing any of that.

I have looked into Toasted Marshmallow but the project seems to be outdated and abandoned. I honestly do not understand how something like allocating very small amount of memory, finding the attribute by string name, checking numeric type, and copying the number into a new spot on stack, could take so long.

Is there any way to speed it up? Are there any tips or tricks? Or is building high performance web apis with Python and Marshmallow impossible?

Comment: YOU know that your example above is a simple transform, but `marshmallow` is a very generic and flexible library for converting this-to-that, and flexibly code always performs more poorly than task-specific code.  It takes a lot of time for marshmallow to figure out what you wanted, and it has to repeat that for every element.  Marshmallow (AND SqlAlchemy) are conveniences, not performance aids.  If performance has become your most important concern, then maybe `marshmallow` isn't right for you.